# Не могу получить текст из окна браузера при помощи pywinauto

Tags: python, pywinauto

Я новичок в программировании и пытаюсь изучать Python. Ранее писал немного на AutoIt и решил один из старых проектов на этом языке программирования реализовать на Python и столкнулся с проблемой.
Был в проекте код, задача которого получить текст из окна браузера Chrome.
Браузер обязательно должен быть запущен с параметром "--force-renderer-accessibility"
Код AutoIt:

```
Func _GetData()
    $oParent = _UIA_GetElementFromHandle(ControlGetHandle("[RegexpTitle:Заголовок окна]", "", "Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND1"))
    $aElements = _UIA_FindAllElements($oParent, "ControlType", $UIA_TextControlTypeId)
    $Text = ""
    For $i = 1 To $aElements[0]
      $Text &= _UIA_ElementGetPropertyValue($aElements[$i], "Name") & " "; & @CRLF
    Next
       ConsoleWrite($Text & @CRLF)
       Return ($Text)
    EndFunc
```

Поиски привели меня к библиотеке pywinauto. Но в готовых примерах по библиотеке я не смог найти ничего похожего на нужный мне функционал. Подключиться к браузеру и вкладке получается без проблем, а дальше я не могу понять как действовать. Подскажите где можно найти информацию по данной проблеме или подскажите пример кода. В ооп к сожалению пока мало разбираюсь, поэтому даже стандартную документацию осилить мне трудно. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку вопрос не указывает на конкретную проблему (а это рекомендуется на StackOverflow), приведу только ссылку на имеющийся пример работы с Хромом: https://github.com/vasily-v-ryabov/ui-automation-course/tree/master/02_google_drive_Murashov

Мы его не добавляли в стандартные примеры, но, возможно, в будущем сделаем это.